# How to add oauth2 package to Eclipse pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, eclipse-indigo

I'm attempting to install the oauth2 package from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2/

This file is (oauth2-1.5.211.tar.gz) .tar.gz format but to add a new library to pydev I need to a .zip or .egg file :

[image]

How can I add this file or an alternative oauth2 library to my pydev installation ?

Comment: Have you tried untarring the oauth2?

Comment: @Karlson the link I gave it to oauth2 ?

Comment: @Karlson update to last comment : the link I gave is to oauth2 ?

Comment: @Karlson yes I have tried untarring but no egg/zip files are extracted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get working use following steps :

install easy_installer :

more info here : http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall
This site should offer a link to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows which contains the easy_installer exe

Once installed ensure the Scripts dir is on your System path, for me this is :

C:\Python27\Scripts

Generate the .egg file by running this command dir where oauth2 (where setup.py is located after extracting the downloaded the oauth2 file) is installed :

```
python setup.py install
```

This should generate the .egg file in 'dist' folder which you can then add via Eclipse UI.

Note : if using 7zip may need to extract download .ta.gz twice, (once on download file and again on generated extracted file) in order to generate python setup files